# What is the different between "присылать" and "посылать"?

Tags: выбор-слова

What is the different between  присылать and послать? With examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While those two verbs indeed are often translated in dictionaries without the same word, I do believe that question is valid and valuable.

In most cases, `прислать` and `послать` are synonyms, yet there is a subtle, but crucial difference in usage.

`Послать`  is just "send" and `прислать` is for action with implication that the message, the letter (or whatever has been send) is already received.

So, one can say "Я послал тебе письмо" or "он послал мне письмо, но оно не дошло, в инбоксе не вижу его".

But, for example "я прислал тебе письмо" (without knowing whether the letter has been received) sounds a bit wrong for native speaker. On the other hand, if message has been received it is more correct to say "Ты прислал мне письмо, я его видел".

Though "ты послал мне письмо" (or "отправил", which is, contrary to `прислал` a full synonym to "послал") wouldn't be considered as a rude offence or even noticed in most cases.

Answer (score 12):

`Послал` means sending was done, without mentioning if it was delivered to the addressee. `Прислал` means it was sent and delivered.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что `письмо прислано` означает то, что оно было отправлено и доставлено. `Письмо послано = письмо отправлено`, но, может быть, ещё не дошло. `При-` and `до-` means arrival. `По-` as well as `от-` and `вы-` means departure.

Answer (score 1):

ПРИ-слать - incoming, end of sending
ПО-слать  - outcoming, start of sending, motion

ПРИ-слать (НАСТОЯЩЕЕ время)

Друг ПРИ-слал мне книгу. (Я держу её в руках; она на почте - скоро заберу; мне везет её курьер - скоро она будет у меня в руках). Действие законченно. 
Друг ПО-слал мне книгу. (Только что отдал в службу доставки и позвонил мне сказать об этом; книга сейчас находится в пути; посылку потеряли и я ей не получу; посылка придет через неделю). Процесс отправки либо только что начался, либо продолжается. Но книга еще не достигла адресата.

ПО-слал и ПРИ-слал могут использоваться в ПРОШЕДШЕМ времени, и в БУДУЩЕМ времени.

В этих случаях ПО-слал и ПРИ-слал используются в зависимости от желания говорящего сделать акцент на личности ОТ-правителя/ПО-лучателя/процесса.

Друг ПО-шлет(ПО-слал) мне книгу. ДРУГ -> мне. Либо факт отправки либо движения(для прошлого времени)
Друг ПРИ-шлет(ПРИ-слал) мне книгу. МНЕ <- книгу. Я УЖЕ получил книгу либо я ПОЛУЧУ(точно, без сомнений) книгу.

НО:

Книгу мне ПО-слал(ПРИ-слал) Бог. Синонимы :). Тут значение имеет КНИГА, ЗНАЧИМОСТЬ и НАЛИЧИЕ оной. В подобном контексте любая фраза будет звучать созвучно библейской "Знамение было послано Богом". Собственно, примерно такой подтекст и вкладывается.

Книгу послал/прислал мне друг. Сам факт отправки/получения/процесса и т.д. не имеет НИКАКОГО значения. Главное "КНИГА от друга", либо "книга от ДРУГА".

Иными словами - если вы хотите указать Факт наличия чего-то/кого-то и источник чего-то/кого-то - то ПРИ.
Если процесс отправки или же сам факт отправки чего-то/кого-то - то ПО.
Если же у вы УЖЕ получили чего-то/кого-то, но значение имеет на сам факт отправки а ПРЕДМЕТ и/или ИСТОЧНИК - то тут на ваш выбор. Особой разницы нет.

(Точнее она есть - но её способны уловить ОЧЕНЬ немногие даже среди русскоговорящих. Очень многие оттенки слов, их порядок, интонация, контекст как правило понятны немногим носителям. И используются ТОЛЬКО при общение между способными понять и оценить вложенный смысл. Либо как шутка(точнее, как правило - ирония/насмешка) понятная ТОЛЬКО говорящему).